# Fill NaN gaps, with mean of bffil and ffill, only if the gaps not exceed 3

Tags: mean, skip, fillna

Following the line of codes that I run:

#count the number of consecutive missing values

'''
df['null'] = df.old.isnull().astype(int).groupby(df.old.notnull().astype(int).cumsum()).sum()
'''

#Fill all missing values

'''
df['new'] = (df['old'].ffill()+df['old'].bfill())/2
'''

#Find the indexes with (previously) more than 3 NaN values and assign NaN to them

'''
df.loc[df['null'] > 3, 'old'] = np.NaN
'''

'''
df.to_excel('result.xlsx', index = False, na_rep='NaN')
'''

That's the result that I obtained

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
#count the number of consecutive missing values
df["null"] = df.yourcolumnname.isnull().astype(int).groupby(df.a.notnull().astype(int).cumsum()).sum()

# Fill all missing values
df["yourcolumnname"] = (df["yourcolumnname"].ffill()+df["yourcolumnname"].bfill())/2

#Find the indexes with (previously) more than 3 NaN values and assign NaN to them
df.loc[df["null"] > 3, "yourcolumnname"] = np.NaN
```

Comment: Dear @Jafar, thank you for your help. I have tried your lines of code bu unfortunately there is something that does not work properly. I seems that the null column does not count as it should and the result is affected by it.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Can you please edit the question and add what you get (error message, incorrect output, etc.)?

Comment: Dear @JafarIsbarov, thank you for your help, I just edit the question as you asked.